# Unit testing with Android XmlPullParser on the JVM

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, jvm, xmlpullparser

I'm trying to set-up unit test cases for my application.

A critical part of the app parses XML files with `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser`. As this part is low-level, isolated and independant from activities, context, views, etc., I really wanted to make it run locally on the JVM, to avoid having to plug or emulate a device all the time.

However when running something like this on the JVM:

```
XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
parser.setInput(in, null);
...
```

I get the famous:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.util.Xml.newPullParser(Xml.java:15)
    ...
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to go around this problem by using [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/) in Android-Studio. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Robolectric/article.html), and stumbled upon [this other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31285965/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-java-lang-system-arraycopy-using-xmlpullparser-with).

Now it works fine except [I can't see the standard output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31275976/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-test) when running tests.

Answer (score 0):

Just like previous comment, I think [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) is the way to go.

I think a code sample could be the welcome so here is mine:

Add the dependancy to you build.gradle :
If you're using android support lib : `testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8'` (AndroidX starts at 4.0)

For other versions : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.robolectric/robolectric

Then in test : (This is Kotlin btw)

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class XmlParserRelTest {
  private lateinit var xmlParserClass : XmlParserClass 

  @Before
  internal fun setUp() {
      xmlParserClass = XmlParserRel(Xml.newPullParser())
  }

  @Test
  fun validFile_parseRelFile_contentIsPresent() {
      val inputStream = getFileInputStream("test.xml")

      val xmlOutput = xmlParserClass.parseRelFile(inputStream )
    
      assertThat(xmlOutput.attribute1).isEqualTo("something")
  }
}
```