# Gradle DSL method not found: test()

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, gradle

Tried to add the following code at the end of my `build.gradle` file in Android-Studio 1.2 (as advised in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963708/gradle-how-to-display-test-results-in-the-console-in-real-time)):

```
test {
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
    }
}
```

But got:

```
Error:(40, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'test()'
Possible causes:
- The project 'xxxxx' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
- The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
```

What did I miss?

Comment: It's android? Shouldn't it be `androidTest`?

Comment: @Opal, Just tried with `androidTest`, but yields the same bug (except instead of `test()`, it's `androidTest()`)

Comment: Did you apply the plugin? It sounds like the extension isn't installed.

Comment: @BenManes Which plugin? I have `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`. I tried to add `apply plugin: 'java'` and/or `apply plugin: 'groovy'`, but these are incompatible with android apparently.

Comment: Can you post a minimal full build file that shows this error? That would help us debug.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The gradle documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html

indicates that the 'test' task is sourced from the java plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'java' // adds 'test' task
```

This as you say conflicts with the com.android.application plugin.

**Solution**

I have finally worked out how to do this. Rather than apply the logging changes to the test tasks (which is only available from java plugin) you can apply it to all tasks of type 'Test' as follows:

```
//Test Logging
tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging {
        events "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

Now when you run `./gradlew test` you should get these events logged as the tests are processed.

Comment: You rock bro! Just FYI to future me: Place this outside of any other closure (i.e not inside android{} block)

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhary you can include this in `android.testOptions.unitTests.all`, then you don't need to filter the tasks first (i.e. leave out the first line).