# Configuring Gradle Test tasks for Android to log events

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I execute Android tests on the command-line using Gradle, I would like to see test log output. I followed the suggestion in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31275976/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-test/31665341#31665341) but events are not being logged.

My app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

...

//Test Logging
tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging {
        events "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

My project has multiple product flavors (free, paid) and build types (debug, release). I expected this would configure these tasks for test logging:

```
connectedAndroidTestPaidDebug
connectedAndroidTestFreeDebug
connectedAndroidTestPaidRelease
...
```

In Android Studio, I see warnings:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'testLogging'
Cannot resolve symbol 'events'
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using :

```
testOptions.unitTests.all {
    testLogging {
        events 'passed', 'skipped', 'failed', 'standardOut', 'standardError'
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I had given up. Thank you for your suggestion. I will give it a try.