# How to configure gradle to output total number of tests executed?

Tags: testing, logging, gradle, configuration, console

While tests are running, the number of tests run *so far* is ephemerally displayed, but how can I print the total number of tests that were run to the console after all tests have run?

Configuring [`testLogging`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogging.html) doesn't help. I can make gradle output a result for *every* test, like this:

```
testLogging {
    events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
}
```

But I want a summary "bottom line", that outputs the total number of tests that were run, *even if they all passed*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may use [afterSuite closure](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:afterSuite(groovy.lang.Closure)) with `TestResult` argument.
F.e. (borrowed from https://gist.github.com/orip/4951642):

```gradle
test {
  testLogging {
    afterSuite { desc, result ->
      if (!desc.parent) { // will match the outermost suite
        println "Results: ${result.resultType} (${result.testCount} tests, ${result.successfulTestCount} successes, ${result.failedTestCount} failures, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I do this I get `Could not find method test() for arguments...`. Any ideas what could cause this? I put it in the app level build.gradle file.

Comment: Looks like it's a little different on Android: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31275976/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-test/31665341#31665341

Comment: @AdamMc331, check you applied Java plugin

Answer (score 3):

**Kotlin DSL** applied answer based on the accepted answer from @Hubbitus (was a bit trickier to adapt than expected):

```
tasks.withType<AbstractTestTask> {
    afterSuite(
        KotlinClosure2({ desc: TestDescriptor, result: TestResult ->
            // Only execute on the outermost suite
            if (desc.parent == null) {
                println(" **** Result: ${result.resultType} ****")
                println("  >    Tests: ${result.testCount}")
                println("  >   Passed: ${result.successfulTestCount}")
                println("  >   Failed: ${result.failedTestCount}")
                println("  >  Skipped: ${result.skippedTestCount}")
            }
        })
    )
}
```

Using `KotlinClosure2` allows the `afterSuite` Groovy closure to be called with the two expected arguments (`TestDescriptor` and `TestResult`) and `Unit` is the return type of the closure (reference: [calling groovy closure from Kotlin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#groovy_closures_from_kotlin)).

Comment: worked like a charm. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using Gradle 2.12 with a simple project (with 2 test suites), this script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

def numTests = 0

test {
    beforeTest { descriptor ->
        logger.lifecycle("Running test: " + descriptor)
        numTests++
    }
}

test << {
    println "\nnumTests executed: ${numTests}"
}
```

gives this output (for me):

```
bash$ gradle clean test
:clean
[snip]
:test
Running test: Test test1(net.codetojoy.ActorTest)
Running test: Test test2(net.codetojoy.ActorTest)
Running test: Test test3(net.codetojoy.ActorTest)
Running test: Test test4(net.codetojoy.ActorTest)
Running test: Test test1(net.codetojoy.SniffTest)
Running test: Test test2(net.codetojoy.SniffTest)
Running test: Test test3(net.codetojoy.SniffTest)
Running test: Test test4(net.codetojoy.SniffTest)
Running test: Test test5(net.codetojoy.SniffTest)
Running test: Test test6(net.codetojoy.SniffTest)

numTests executed: 10
```

Comment: It gets the job done, but I'm looking for a configuration/setting approach - it seems reasonable that there should be a simple way of outputting it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Android solution based on @Hubbitus's answer and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31665341/902832)

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.plugins.findPlugin('android') ?: project.plugins.findPlugin('android-library')) {
            tasks.withType(Test) {
                testLogging {
                    events "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed"

                }
                afterSuite { desc, result ->
                    if (!desc.parent) { // will match the outermost suite
                        println "Results: ${result.resultType} (${result.testCount} tests, ${result.successfulTestCount} successes, ${result.failedTestCount} failures, ${result.skippedTestCount} skipped)"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which goes in my root build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Gradle writes XML files in `test-reports` that are easy to parse. You can for an example parse them with a [Kotlin script](https://selfformat.com/blog/2022/09/15/how-to-quickly-write-and-run-kotlin-script/):

```kotlin
@file:DependsOn("net.mbonnin.xoxo:xoxo:0.3")

import xoxo.toXmlDocument
import java.io.File

File(".").walk().filter { it.name == "test-results" && it.isDirectory }
    .toList()
    .flatMap {
      it.walk().filter { it.isFile && it.extension == "xml" }.toList()
    }
    .map {
       it.toXmlDocument()
          .root
          .attributes["tests"]!!
          .toInt()
    }
    .sum()
```