# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.System.arraycopy using XmlPullParser with Robolectric

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric, xmlpullparser

I am trying to test my Android app in Android-Studio with Robolectric. One of my unit tests makes use of `XmlPullParser`:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("somefile.xml"));
XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
parser.setInput(in, null);
parser.nextTag();
while(parser.next()!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
    // ...
}
```

Here is what happens when I run the test:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.System.arraycopy([II[III)V
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.parseStartTag(KXmlParser.java:1145)
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:372)
    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:313)
    at xxx.Xxxx.readTag(Xxxx.java:167)
```

Is it a problem with the implementation of the parser on Robolectric side?

Comment: change your api version

Comment: @Exbury Thank you! Indeed it works when I switch to API 18!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problems i faced few months back. Change your android API version error will be lost. More info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501042/android-app-in-eclipse-edit-text-not-showing-on-graphical-layout).

Answer (score 3):

In case somebody stumbles upon this problem, it comes from the version of the SDK.

In the test case just switch from:

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21, manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
```

to:

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 18, manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
```

Thanks @Exbury for the tip!